# C++ reading data from external device - connection: OPTO-USB

Tags: c++, serial-port, usb

I was looking for some information about connecting a dial gauge (I'm not sure if it is called like that) made by Sylvac with program written in C++. The connection is by OPTO-USB cable (number 926.6621.10). Data format: X.XX (in millimeters).

I tried to use MSDN functions: `CreateFile`, `ReadFile`. There is no error, neither any value. Transmission settings should be correct (I found them on CD attached to the cable).

Does someone have any idea how to read data from dial gauge? I tried to convert data in a few ways. "cout" under each function was used to find the place, where program stops. I wrote this code using some on the Internet.

Edit on 2014-01-10

There is still problem with my program. The dial gauge shows "0,04" on the display, so I expect the same value in my program in "buffor" variable, but there is nothing. Even "read" is zero.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    LPBYTE buffor = new BYTE[64];
    *buffor = 1;
    HANDLE file;
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts;
    DWORD read;
    DCB port;
    char port_name[128] = "\\\\.\\COM3";
    cout << "pierwszy: " << endl;

    // open the comm port.
    file = CreateFile((port_name), GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if ( file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
        cout << "1 1";
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // get the current DCB, and adjust a few bits to our liking.
        memset(&port, 0, sizeof(port));
        port.DCBlength = sizeof(port);
        if ( !GetCommState(file, &port))
            cout << " 2 ";
        if (!BuildCommDCB(("baud=4800 parity=e data=7 stop=2"), &port))
            cout << " 3 ";
        if (!SetCommState(file, &port))
            cout << " 4 ";

        port.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;
        port.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_ENABLE;

        BOOL success;
        success = GetCommTimeouts(file, &timeouts);
        if (!success)
        {
            cout << "error";
            CloseHandle(file);
            return 1;//INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        }
        timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 1000;
        timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 1000;
        timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
        timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 1000;
        timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
        success = SetCommTimeouts(file, &timeouts);
        if (!success)
        {
            cout << "error";
            CloseHandle(file);
            return 1;//INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        }

        if (!EscapeCommFunction(file, CLRDTR))
           cout << " 7 ";
        Sleep(200);
        if (!EscapeCommFunction(file, SETDTR))
           cout << " 8 ";

        // check for data on port and display it on screen.
        if(ReadFile(file, &buffor, sizeof(buffor), &read, NULL))
        {
            cout << "buffor: " << buffor << endl;
            cout << "read = " << read << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < read; i++ )
                cout << i+1 << ". " << buffor[i] << endl;

            cout << "." << endl;
        }
        else
            cout << "error read";

        delete buffor;
        CloseHandle(file);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I put here the result in console: [console](http://www.speedyshare.com/te33D/kon.png)

Variables expected:
buffor -> 0,04; 
read -> number of read bytes

Output variables:
buffor ???? Nothing?; 
read = 0

Comment: Could you provide the exact model number of the actual dial gauge and links to all the documentation?  Without that, we would just have to guess.

Comment: How does the code behave, and how does that differ from what you expect?  You said it "stops", but what line?

Comment: The dial gauge number is: S229, type: 12.5mm / 0.01 (I'm not sure, but there is another number: 905.1201 )

I've found something like that: http://www.sylvac.ch/doc/print_vm_cat_11_en-GB.pdf

Now, there is no error (the program will stop only when an error occurs). But the variable, that contains the number value from the dial gauge, is empty. I think it's not a problem with conversion between different types of variables but connection.

Comment: Saying that some variable is "empty" doesn't really help because it's hard to know what variable you are talking about and your assessment might be wrong.  You should copy and paste the entire output of your program here and explicitly point out which lines are wrong and say why.

Comment: [image](http://speedy.sh/a7VdG/konsola.png).
This is an example of program's results. After "odczytane:", "cout buffer:", "o:" and "o atol:" there should be the numerical value from dial gauge. Instad I have some scrawl ;]

Comment: There is another example (after few changes): [image2](http://speedy.sh/RP4KU/konsola.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking long time for the solution until I found. The answer is very simple!
There are two ways to transfer data from this dial gauge to the computer:

1. You can set event-mask using function [`SetCommMask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then wait for event that you declared using function `WaitCommEvent`.
2. You can send some character to the dial gauge using [`WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then just read with: `ReadFile`.

My code:

```
if(WriteFile(Sensor, " ", 1, &read, NULL))
    ReadFile(Sensor, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &read, NULL);
```

buffer is `LPBYTE` so I have to convert it:

```
char buf[4];

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    buf[i] = buffer[i];

double buff = 0;
buff = atof(buf);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the additional information provided in the comments, we can start to diagnose this.  The actual problem for you is that junk is getting printed after the word "odczytane".  This information should have been in the first post, by the way.

First of all, you need to ensure that your program is set up to do **blocking** reads.  You have set some very short reading timeouts, which means that whenever you try to read data from the file your program will give up very quickly.  Your program is probably giving up before any data is ready.  Try increasing each of those to 1000 ms by doing something similar to he following code:

```
    BOOL success;
    success = GetCommTimeouts(port, &timeouts);
if (!success)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to get comm timeouts.  Error code 0x%x.\n", GetLastError());
    CloseHandle(port);
    return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}
timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 1000;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 1000;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 1000;
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
success = SetCommTimeouts(port, &timeouts);
if (!success)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to set comm timeouts.  Error code 0x%x.\n", GetLastError());
    CloseHandle(port);
    return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}
```

You might need to make those even longer depending on the details of your device.

Another basic problem here is that you are not thinking carefully about the format of the data returned by ReadFile.

`ReadFile` is a generally useful function for reading any kind of data (i.e. binary).  It does not append a null termination character at the end of the data as far as I know.  (It shouldn't, because you might want to read some 0 bytes.)  You need to look at the value of `read` after calling `ReadFile` to know how many bytes were read.

Things like `printf` and cout need to be passed a null-terminated string.

Printing `sizeof(read)` will always give you a 4 because `read` is just defined to be a 32-bit integer (`DWORD`).

Putting all this knowledge together, here is a reasonable way we could call ReadFile and print the results.  I don't know if the returned data is ASCII or binary so I will just print the numeric value of each byte:

```
if(ReadFile(file, buffor, sizeof(buffor), &read, NULL))
{
  cout << "bytes read:" << read << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < read; i++)
  {
    cout << buffor[i] << " " << endl;
  }
}
else
{
  cout << "ReadFile failed" << endl;
}
```

I haven't looked carefully at how this particular serial device works, so there might be a problem with how you set it up that would cause it to not send data.

If you continue to have trouble, please simplify your program to a single file less than 100 lines long and provide the entire code, along with the output and the expected output.  http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to add these advices to my program and check if it works:)